# Nunit using an object in TestCaseSource or TestCase

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I have just completed my first unit test class but was left feeling frustrated that I was copied and pasted so much of my logic. After some searching I found that `[TestCaseSource]` or `[TestCase]` was what I potentially needed, but whe I use `[TestCaseSource]` I get the below message

> Result Message:   The sourceName specified on a TestCaseSourceAttribute must refer to a static field, property or method.

or for `[TestCase]`

> Error  1   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Below is my code for using `[TestCaseSource]` (I have removed the other items in testCaseInput to keep it easier to read)

```
private SomeFormValidator SomeFormValidator;
    private static MyClass _myClass { get; set; }
    private readonly object[] testCaseInput =
    {
        new object[] { typeof(MyClass), "MyClass is required", _myClass },
    };

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        SomeFormValidator = new SomeFormValidator ();
        _myClass = new MyClass();
    }

    [Test, TestCaseSource("testCaseInput")]
    public void Should_have_error_message_when_property_is_null(string message, object property)
    {
        var result = SomeFormValidator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x=> x.MyClass , property);
        result.WithErrorMessage(message);
    }
```

Below is my code for using `[TestCase]` (I have removed the other items to keep it easier to read)

```
private SomeFormValidator SomeFormValidator;
    const MyClass _myClass = new MyClass();
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        SomeFormValidator = new SomeFormValidator();
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCase("MyClassis required", _myClass )]
    public void Should_have_error_message_when_property_is_null(string message, object property)
    {

        var result = SomeFormValidator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(aup => aup.MyClass, property);
        result.WithErrorMessage(message);
    }
```

Comment: `testCaseInput` is only `private readonly`, it also needs to be `static`

Comment: There is nothing upsetting in copy pasting some pieces (usually Arrange section) from test to test if the tests are small and simple. If they are not, _setup_ or _source_ methods will hardly solve the problem. There is a great [article](http://jamesnewkirk.typepad.com/posts/2007/09/why-you-should-.html) about that.

Answer (score 1):

For `TestCaseSource` attribute you should use `static` member:

```
private static readonly object[] testCaseInput = ...
```

Attributes are metadata which should be known at compile time. You are trying to pass instance of `MyClass` to attribute. But class instance can be created only at runtime. Actually you can pass to atrributes only constants (such as strings, booleans or numbers), `typeof` expression (i.e. you can pass `typeof(MyClass)`) or array creation expression (e.g. `new [] { 1, 2, 3 }`).

In your case you can pass error message and property name to test method:

```
[TestCase("MyClass is required", "MyClass")]
public void BlahBlah(string message, string propertyName)
```

Comment: Great answer, very well explained. I would use the `nameof()` operator to obtain the simple (unqualified) string name of your static variable so you don't have to hardcode the name:
 `[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(testCaseInput ))]`